# PHP как сделать autoload из нескольких папок?

Tags: php, ооп, mvc

Сейчас работает так:

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {include 'core/' . $class . '.php'; });
 $app = new App();
```

Есть папка `core` куда я складываю файлы классов. Сейчас их стало много, и хочется разделить на модели, виды, контроллеры
Подскажите как сделать так, чтобы он искал классы из списка папок (массив)?

Comment: Я бы порекомендовал просто использовать composer autoload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно как-то так:

```php
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    $baseDir = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'core' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    $file = $baseDir . str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, rtrim($class, '\\')) . '.php';
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        require_once $file;
    }
});
```

Теперь классы контроллеров можно вынести в директорию `core/Controllers` и в этих файлах после `<?php` указать `namespase Controllers;` (регистр важен)
например, файл `core/Controllers/HomeController.php` будет выглядеть как-то так:

```php
<?php

namespace Controllers;

class HomeController
{
    // тут содержимое
}
```

Но лучше освоить `composer` - тогда можно вообще забыть про самописную автозагрузку, про заморочки с подключением сторонних библиотек, про перенос своего кода между проектами и т.д.